# How do I get the path of a jackson JsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a json that looks something like this

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": [
            {
                "c": {
                    "d": [{ "f": "value" }]
                }
            },
            {
                "c": {
                    "d": [{ "f": "value" }]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm looping the data inside `b` using the following code, then getting the array at `d` again in a nested loop

```
for (JsonNode abNode : rootNode.at("/a/b")) {
    for (JsonNode cdNode : abNode.at("/c/d")) {
        //cdNode.get("f")
    }
}
```

Inside the for loop how can I get the path of something like `node.get("f")` so that I would get `/a/b/0/c/d/0/f` and then `/a/b/1/c/d/0/f`? Does jackson have something to get this or another library? The only thing I can think of right now is just switching to a `for i=0` loop

Comment: I'm not sure the nodes would provide that path so I'd also either switch to a traditional for-loop or just track the index in the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is also called as Xpath in technical terms.
It is used for html, xml based languages as well as now available in json

You can try jsonpath for this case:

https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 0):

Google's popular GSON library has a method, namely `getPath`, maybe useful for your purpose:

```
String json = "...";
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(json));
System.out.println(reader.getPath());
```